# merge two CSS classes taking grid from one framework and style from another one

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I've read previous questions on this topic, but none of them ask what I'm trying to do. I'd like to merge two CSS classes (from two frameworks). More specifically I'd like to use the grid from one framework (like bootstrap) and style from another one. So when I style a button, for example, I want attributes related to locate an element in the view defined in the framework that I use for its grid system and attributes related to style from the other one. Here an example

```
.grid-class {
  definition1; // something related to width, margin padding
  definition2; // something like color, font-family
}

.layout-class {
 definition1; // something related to width, margin padding
 definition2; // something like color, font-family
}
```

if I give grid-class layout-class to an element I'd like to have something like this:

```
.merged-class { // I do not need to create a CSS class on the fly
   definition1; // from grid class
   definition2; // from layout class
}
```

I know that merge two frameworks is more complex, but **I'd like to know if it's possible and how using JavaScript/TypeScript**. I know which class is related with grid and which one is related with the layout because I'm using Angular and I have two binding like this:

```
<my-component [grid]="grid classes" [layout]="layout classes"></my-component>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "merge." Are you trying to automate a combination of the two stylesheets together, or are you wondering if there's some sort of css/js selector that does something to the effect of ``.merged-class { .grid-class; .layout-class; }``? I'm wondering why ``<element class="grid-class layout-class"></element>`` doesn't work for you. I suppose it would just be inconsistencies between the two classes. But no, I'm unaware of anything that performs this function in CSS.

Comment: I gave an example of what I'd like to achieve, as i said I want to take grid related css statement from one framework and layout related (like color) from the other framework and as I said I use javascript and not css

Comment: Alright a javascript function that combines classes then. Do you envision passing the two classes as parameters, or passing the specific attributes as well? There has to be some way of determining which definition you prefer per attribute in the class, so you'd likely need to pass through every relevant parameter to your combiner function.